In Python, what is the space complexity of list1[::] = list2?
This code (a solution to this LeetCode challenge) first iterates through a list nums, updating counts of integers 0, 1, 2, also called red, white, and blue respectively. nums is guaranteed to only have the integers 0, 1, and/or 2. After finding the counts, the code uses [::], a trick to modify a list in-place, to sort nums.
def sortColors(nums: List[int]) -> None:
    red = white = blue = 0

    for num in nums:
        match num:
            case 0:
                red += 1
            case 1:
                white += 1
            case 2:
                blue += 1

    # [::] to modify nums in-place - Space O(1)
    nums[::] = ([0] * red) + ([1] * white) + ([2] * blue)

I thought ([0] * red) + ([1] * white) + ([2] * blue) would be evaluated before modifying nums, meaning that list would have to be created and stored in memory before nums[::] = can proceed. To me, this makes sense, since in Python the right side of = is evaluated before variable assignment, which makes things like x = x + 1 work. So, under this understanding, at this point in the code, both the original nums list and the new list would be stored in memory. Because the new list will be the same length as nums, O(n) additional space is needed.
However, LeetCode's analyzer said this code was O(1) space. The only thing I can think of is that the moment nums[::] = is called, the code ignores the original contents of nums and modifies nums in-place to the new list.
How is this O(1) space, and is my understanding of space complexity and variable assignment correct?

Perhaps that's as bad as their time measurement, i.e., includes judge overhead. So that taking O(1) or O(n) space is both insignificant compared to 13 MB baseline usage.

Especially since n <= 300.

Your assessment that the code you've shown takes O(n) extra space to temporarily build a new list with the sorted values is correct. It's possible to do a counting sort like this in O(1) space, but the code to implement it in Python is just a little more complicated:
def sortColors(nums: List[int]) -> None:
    red = white = blue = 0

    for num in nums:
        match num:
            case 0:
                red += 1
            case 1:
                white += 1
            case 2:
                blue += 1

    assert len(nums) == red+white+blue

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = (i >= red) + (i >= red+white)  # note: bool+bool->int

This will use only O(1) extra memory, since only the red, white and blue counters take up space beyond the starting nums list.
Note that a lot of other, more Pythonic styles of programming are likely to allocate O(n) temporary memory in the background, at least in some situations.
For example, if you assign an itertools.repeat iterator to a slice (e.g. nums[:red] = itertools.repeat(0, red)), you won't consume O(n) memory directly in the same way as the original code (since the iterator takes only constant memory), but the slice assignment will dump the iterator into a temporary list in the background so that it can know if it needs to resize the list (it doesn't, but it can't know that in advance).
Similarly, if you clear() the list and then extend() it with itertools.repeat iterators, the resizing logic of the list might temporarily consume O(n) extra memory as it copies the list items into a larger section of memory (thanks to user no comment who pointed this out in the comments).
I'd also note that list.sort is probably faster for most reasonable lengths of list, even though its asymptotic complexity is worse than your code's counting sort! Having a very well written implementation in C is a big advantage! Of course, it probably does allocate at least some extra memory (probably O(n) space in the worst case, but I haven't checked).

I think yours isn't O(1) space but only O(n). When you extend with the blues, the list doesn't have room for them, so it reallocates to make room, temporarily using up to twice as much memory as originally used by the input.

@nocomment No, extending with an iterator that has an accurate __length_hint__ method (as itertools.repeat instances do) will not cause the list to over-allocate space. It will wind up using exactly as much space as is needed. The existence of __length_hint__ was one of the reasons I mentioned "reliably" and "strictly" in the text of my answer, as iterators that support it are handled more efficiently for some operations (such as extend, which doesn't mind some potential imprecision) but not others (such as slice assignment, which needs an exact length).

I didn't say anything about over-allocating. Please read my comment again.

@nocomment Could you elaborate please?

@CrazyChucky Let's say the counts are n-1, 0, and 1. Before appending the one blue, the list takes n-1 memory. Since it didn't over-allocate, it has no room for the blue. So it reallocates. To a memory region with size n. If it's lucky, the memory spot right after the n-1 isn't used and it can reallocate in place. But if it isn't that lucky, the reallocation means allocating new n memory elsewhere and copying the current n-1 into it. During that, (n-1)+n memory is used. (At least as far as I know, I admit I haven't read the reallocation code).

At least in CPython, list.sort indeed takes O(N) extra space, up to 4 bytes per element (merging temporarily moves up to N/2 element references of 8 bytes each to some temp memory).

Your tool is lying to you.  If you look at the disassembled code:
import dis
dis.dis(sortColors)

It is clear that the code is building the right side of the final assignment as a list, and then only afterwards calling the STORE_SLICE opcode to store the right-side value into the left-hand slice. It has no knowledge until then that the two are the same size.
